# Querying for an ID that has the most number of reads

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table like the one below:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |   TIME    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 12-MAR-15 |
|  2 | 23-APR-14 |
|  2 | 01-DEC-14 |
|  1 | 01-DEC-15 |
|  3 | 05-NOV-15 |
+----+-----------+
```

What I want to do is for each year ( the year is defined as DATE), list the ID that has the highest count in that year. So for example, ID 1 occurs the most in 2015, ID 2 occurs the most in 2014, etc.

What I have for a query is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from time) "YEAR", COUNT(ID) "ID"
FROM table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from time)
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

But this query just counts how many times a year occurs, how do I fix it to highest count of an ID in that year?

**Output:**

```
+------+----+
| YEAR | ID |
+------+----+
| 2015 |  2 |
| 2012 |  2 |
+------+----+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+------+----+
| YEAR | ID |
+------+----+
| 2015 |  1 |
| 2014 |  2 |
+------+----+
```

Comment: can you please put up the results you are getting and the expected results. Thanks

Comment: @KamranFarzami edited above to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your sample query, the first change is simply to group by the ID as well as by the year.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from time) "YEAR" , id, COUNT(*) "TOTAL"
FROM table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from time), id
ORDER BY EXTRACT(year from time) DESC, COUNT(*) DESC
```

With that, you could find the rows you want by visual inspection (the first row for each year is the ID with the most rows).

To have the query just return the rows with the highest totals, there are several different ways to do it.  You need to consider what you want to do if there are ties - do you want to see all IDs tied for highest in a year, or just an arbitrary one?

Here is one approach - if there is a tie, this should return just the lowest of the tied IDs:

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(year from time) "YEAR" , id, COUNT(*) "TOTAL"
  FROM table
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from time), id
)
SELECT year, MIN(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY total DESC)
FROM groups
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to count per id and then apply a RANK on that count:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT EXTRACT(year from time) "YEAR" , ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "YEAR" ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM table
   GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from time), ID
 ) dt
WHERE rnk = 1
```

If this return multiple rows with the same high count per year and you want just one of them randomly, you can switch to a ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after, I think:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, to_date('12/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') time from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('23/04/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') time from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('01/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') time from dual union all
                     select 1 id, to_date('01/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') time from dual union all
                     select 3 id, to_date('05/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') time from dual)
-- End of creating a subquery to mimick a table called "sample_data" containing your input data.
-- See SQL below:
select yr,
       id most_frequent_id,
       cnt_id_yr cnt_of_most_freq_id
from   (select   to_char(time, 'yyyy') yr,
                 id,
                 count(*) cnt_id_yr,
                 dense_rank() over (partition by to_char(time, 'yyyy') order by count(*) desc) dr
        from     sample_data
        group by to_char(time, 'yyyy'),
                 id)
where  dr = 1;

YR   MOST_FREQUENT_ID CNT_OF_MOST_FREQ_ID
---- ---------------- -------------------
2014                2                   2
2015                1                   2
```